# Making a sub-domain reachable only using sub-domain name not by adding slash at the end

Tags: .htaccess, dns, hosting, subdomain

I'm developing a PHP site and it has two parts. Front-end and Back-end. I'm planning to include the front-end in the main domain **www.mydomain.com**
while including the back-end in a sub-domain like this  **system.mydomain.com**

I have my sub-domain folder inside the main domain folder.

So, my problem is my users can visit the back-end by adding a `/`to the main domain like this. **www.mydomain.com/system**

So, I want to block that way of visiting the back-end and allow users to visit the back-end only through the sub-domain URL **(system.mydomain.com)**

So, how to do that..?

P.S: I'm not much familiar with these words so, apologies for any misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

Check this solution

http://www.codefleet.net/prevent-access-to-subdomain-folder-from-main-domain/